# Can't download genderdata for R 4.2.0

Tags: r

Update: I brought my laptop and used a different wifi. And now it works!

I tried to install `genderdata` to R with the following code,

`remotes::install_github("lmullen/genderdata")`

I got the following error message:

```
Downloading GitHub repo lmullen/genderdata@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/lmullen/genderdata/tarball/HEAD' failed
```

My R version is 4.2.0.

I have tried other ways and I got the same error message:

`devtools::install_github("ropensci/genderdata")`

Comment: Try the ["lmullen/genderdata"](https://github.com/lmullen/genderdata) repository. And [R 4.3.2](https://cran.r-project.org/) was just released, time to update R?

Comment: That does seem like an odd error. Can you get to https://api.github.com/repos/lmullen/genderdata/tarball/HEAD in your browser? Does anything in your network block you from access to that site?

Comment: @MrFlick, I could get that link in my browser. What does that file do?

Comment: @Rui Barradas: I'm very new to R. How do I try the "lmullen/genderdata" repository? I'll look into updating R. Thanks!

Comment: That file contains the contents of the package that R is trying to install. Are you behind a proxy server perhaps? That's odd it will download in your browser and not R. Do you get the same error with `download.file("https://api.github.com/repos/lmullen/genderdata/tarball/HEAD")` in R? Are you using windows? What does `getOption("download.file.method")` return?

Comment: @Rebecca Folll my comment link  an you will find instructions to download the package from GitHub. Try `remotes::install_github("lmullen/genderdata")`. Or `devtools::install_github("lmullen/genderdata")`.

Comment: @MrFlick I don't think I'm behind a proxy server. I'm using windows. The first command shows the error with `argument "destfile" is missing, with no default` And the second command shows `"libcurl"`

Comment: @Rui Barradas I tried both and they don't work.